# Binding to Viewmodel Collection inside ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewmodel, itemtemplate

I'm new to this so bear with me.

I have a viewmodel and an view with an ItemsControl with some data already in it, with its own source of items.

However I effectively want to number the items in the control, because there are always 10 of them. I could do this by just adding a load of textblocks along the left side but this is just tedious and I'm trying to find a different way.

So this is the gist of what I have so far:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.Nums}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item1}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Item2}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

My problem is that of course it is just displaying the same item for each one which in this case is "(Collection)" because I have a list property with 1-10 in it.

Binding to this in a separate .cs file:

```
private List<int> _nums = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

public List<int> Nums
{
    get { return _nums; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So I found a solution by making a new property within the itemssource that was a string and then with some jiggering around with the way my app collects the source data I was able to get it to work consistently.

I'm still interested if this method would have worked however, in my opinion it would have been a lot less work.

Comment: Can you show the structure of the class that you are binding?

Comment: The actual itemsource is from a property in my viewmodel, basically I'm just trying to use a second property as a source?

Comment: The TextBlock does not support templating (in the manner you refer to it).  Just based upon what you wrote, the immediate suggestion is to replace the first TextBlock with MyUserControl.

Comment: May I introduce you to the `Enumerable.Range` method? It's very handy: `List<int> _nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();`. Clearly, it's more useful with bigger ranges.

Comment: Interesting, not really used Linq much at all thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest thing to do in my opinion, is to simply add an `int` property into your data type or data view model class and then `Bind` directly to that in your `ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Number}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item1}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Item2}" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In WPF, we generally try to create a view model class for each view that has *all* of the data that we need to display in it.

UPDATE >>>

Ignore the numbers that may or may not come with the data... just add an `int Number` property and leave it set to 0 when you fill the other properties with data. When you pass the data to the view model, just iterate through it, numbering it correctly. Assuming your collection is named `Items`, you could do this:

```
for (int index = 1; index < Items.Count; index++)
{
    Items[index - 1].Number = index;
}
```

Comment: This is difficult for me, because of the nature of the data I'm using. Originally it was this way. I'm importing files which do have the numbers in but in some cases the file has only got say 2 - 6 and I end up with a list of 10 where the empty slots have 0s I experimented with converting them to chars/string so I could have a space instead of a 0, but then I moved on to attempting this way. Basically I'm just learning/experimenting with different options I just wondered if it was possible to make this work